# Property 'navigation' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another by using React Navigation .But found this issue.

I tried it by following React Navigation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you haven't add navigation property in your function.
I'm attaching an example of my Splash screen navigation for your reference.

```
const Splash = ({navigation}) => {    //Add navigation here inside your function
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
  }, 2000);

  return (
   //Code
  );
};
```

So just add `{navigation}` inside your arrow function. That'll work.